# How to import pyspark in anaconda

Tags: python, apache-spark, anaconda, pyspark

I am trying to import and use `pyspark` with anaconda.

After installing spark, and setting the `$SPARK_HOME` variable I tried:

```
$ pip install pyspark
```

This won't work (of course) because I discovered that I need to tel python to look for `pyspark` under `$SPARK_HOME/python/`. The problem is that to do that, I need to set the `$PYTHONPATH` while anaconda don't use that environment variable.

I tried to copy the content of `$SPARK_HOME/python/` to `ANACONDA_HOME/lib/python2.7/site-packages/` but it won't work.

Is there any solution to use pyspark in anaconda?

Comment: [PySpark installation guide](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/getting_started/install.html).

Answer (score 20):

This may have only become possible recently, but I used the following and it worked perfectly.  After this, I am able to 'import pyspark as ps' and use it with no problems.

`conda install -c conda-forge pyspark`

Comment: It is amazing how in the past two years conda-forge has made things take 30 seconds that used to take 3 days.

Answer (score 9):

You can simply set `PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON` and `PYSPARK_PYTHON` environmental variables to use either root Anaconda Python or a specific Anaconda environment. For example:

```
export ANACONDA_ROOT=~/anaconda2
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=$ANACONDA_ROOT/bin/ipython
export PYSPARK_PYTHON=$ANACONDA_ROOT/bin/python
```

or

```
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=$ANACONDA_ROOT/envs/foo/bin/ipython 
export PYSPARK_PYTHON=$ANACONDA_ROOT/envs/foo/bin/python
```

When you use `$SPARK_HOME/bin/pyspark` / `$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-submit`  it will choose a correct environment. Just remember that PySpark has to the same Python version on all machines.

On a side note using `PYTHONPATH` should work just fine, even if it is not recommended.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could I import `pyspark` in a standalone mode? I mean `import pyspark`

Comment: It is not a very precise description... What exactly doesn't work. What exactly doesn't work. And just for the record - using `PYTHONPATH` should work just fine. It is just not recommended.

Answer (score 2):

Here are the complete set of environment variables I had to put in my .bashrc to get this to work in both scripts and notebook

```
export ANACONDA_ROOT=~/anaconda2
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=$ANACONDA_ROOT/bin/ipython
export PYSPARK_PYTHON=$ANACONDA_ROOT/bin/python

export SPARK_HOME=/opt/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7
export PYLIB=/opt/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib

export PYTHONPATH=$SPARK_HOME/python:$SPARK_HOME/python/lib:$PYTHONPATH
export PYTHONPATH=$SPARK_HOME/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip:$PYTHONPATH
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this can help someone, According to the [Anaconda documentation](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/findspark), you install FindSpark as follows:

```
conda install -c conda-forge findspark
```

It was only after installing it as showned about that I was able to import FindSpark. No export statements required.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that you need nor can install pyspark as a module. Instead, I extended my `$PYTHONPATH` in my ~/.bash_profile as follows:

`export PYTHONPATH=$SPARK_HOME/python:$SPARK_HOME/python/build:$PYTHONPATH`

After that, I was able to `import pyspark as ps`. Hope that works for you too.

Comment: What exists in `$SPARK_HOME/python/build`? I can't find the `build` directory included in my spark distribution (spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.4).

Answer (score 0):

Hey there you could try these running these lines in the Anaconda powershell instead. Straight from https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/findspark

```
To install this package with conda run one of the following:
conda install -c conda-forge findspark
conda install -c conda-forge/label/gcc7 findspark
conda install -c conda-forge/label/cf201901 findspark
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use that command which will help you to install lower version of pyspark

pip install pyspark==3.x.x

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).