# Anaconda3 is installed, jupyter notebook errors out No module named 'pyspark'

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, jupyter-notebook

I have been searching in stackoverflow and other places for the error I am seeing now and tried a few "answers", none is working here (I will continue search though and update here):

I have a new Ubuntu and Anaconda3 is installed, Spark 2 is installed:

Anaconda3: /home/rxie/anaconda
Spark2: /home/rxie/Downloads/spark

I am able to start up Jupyter Notebook, however, not able to create SparkSession:

```
from pyspark.conf import SparkConf
```

> ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>   ----> 1 from pyspark.conf import SparkConf
>
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyspark'

Here is my environments in the .bashrc:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
export SPARK_HOME=/home/rxie/spark/
export SBT_HOME=/usr/share/sbt/bin/sbt-launch.jar
export SCALA_HOME=/usr/local/src/scala/scala-2.10.4
export PATH=$SCALA_HOME/bin:$PATH
export PATH=$SPARK_HOME/bin:$PATH
export PATH=$PATH:$SBT_HOME/bin:$SPARK_HOME/bin

# added by Anaconda3 installer
export PATH="/home/rxie/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
export PATH=$SPARK_HOME/bin:$PATH
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=jupyter
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS='notebook'
```

What's wrong with the import SparkConf in jupyter notebook?

It is greatly appreciated if anyone can shed me with any light, thank you very much.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to import pyspark in anaconda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33814005/how-to-import-pyspark-in-anaconda)

Comment: By the way, you duplicated `$SPARK_HOME/bin:$PATH`

Comment: You say you have Spark at `/home/rxie/Downloads/spark`... but what is `SPARK_HOME=/home/rxie/spark/`?

Comment: One more: Try using https://github.com/minrk/findspark

Comment: Thank you @cricket_007, I corrected the wrong SPARK_HOME but error remains the same.

Comment: after source `~/.bashrc`, and `exec bash`, it is working now, thank you

Comment: hmmm, it seems the error is related to the folder where I start the notebook instance? failed again with same error

Comment: Still no clue on what happened, same error here. :(

Comment: If you use that findspark package, it shouldn't matter where the shell is started. All bash sessions should be loading `SPARK_HOME`. Personally, I use Apache Toree https://stackoverflow.com/a/39181257/2308683

Comment: no need to use findspark but thank you for your hints.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

With the final PATH be the following, the notebook starts working as expected:

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/lib64/qt-.3/bin:/home/rxie/perl5/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin
```

AND:

```
echo $PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON
jupyter
echo $PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS
notebook
```

Comment: Well, nothing on your PATH there is Spark specific, so that doesn't seem to be the solution

Comment: would it be because of the two variables? they were blank before

Comment: No, everything after `/usr/lib64/qt-.3/bin:/home/rxie/perl5/bin` is default OS path settings. And those two things are QT and Perl, so nothing on your PATH is Spark related.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, jupyter doesn't works correctly when is installed with Anaconda. I was the same problem and I solved it reinstalling the jupyter package in the virtual environment.

In your virtual environment do:

```
pip install jupyter
```

Comment: Thanks. Re-install jupyter is not always acceptable in some situation. I believe in this case the blank value in the two variables is the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in python, you need to initialize your spark session

```
import os
import sys
spark_home = os.environ.get('SPARK_HOME', None)
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(spark_home, 'python'))
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(spark_home, 'python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip'))
execfile(os.path.join(spark_home, 'python/pyspark/shell.py'))
```

Above is my code, you may need to find the corresponding libraries in your spark installation and replace the paths above.

If you lucky, you will see something like this

```
Python 2.7.13 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Sep 22 2017, 00:47:24)
[GCC 7.2.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /__ / .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 2.2.1-mapr-1803
      /_/

Using Python version 2.7.13 (default, Sep 22 2017 00:47:24)
SparkSession available as 'spark'.
>>> from pyspark.conf import SparkConf
>>> SparkConf
<class 'pyspark.conf.SparkConf'>
>>>
```